# Unable to connect front end to back end while following a tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io, use-effect

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwFA3YMfkoc&ab_channel=JavaScriptMastery (github: https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_chat_application) trying to create a real time chat app and I am unable to make a connection and I am unable to find what the issue is especially since my code looks exactly the same as the video.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; enter code hereimport queryString from "query-string"; import io from "socket.io-client";

import "./Chat.css";

let socket;

export default function Chat({ location }) {   const [name, setName] = useState("");   const [room, setRoom] = useState("");   const ENDPOINT
= "localhost:5000";   console.log("logging!");   useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    setRoom(room);
    setName(name);
console.log(name,room)

    socket.emit("join", { name, room }, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    });   }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

  return <div>Hello World</div>; }
```

The console.log I put in isnt logging either and when I check the console this is the message I get repreatedly:

```
polling-xhr.js:202 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NSV19AI net::ERR_FAILED
```

The message I am expecting to get is an io object with "name" and "room" and also a "we have a new connection!!!" on the back end. This is the back end I am trying to connect to which as far as I've seen is working fine:

```
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const http = require("http");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const router = require("./router");
const { callbackify, isRegExp } = require("util");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("we have a new connection!!!");

  socket.on("join", ({ name, room }) => {
    console.log(name, room);
    const error = true;
    if (error) {
      callback({ error: "error" });
    }
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected :O!");
  });
});

app.use(router);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

I've been away from React and Express for a few months now so its likely there is something obvious I'm missing but when the useEffect console.log isnt logging anything I know something strange is happening.

This is the first time I will have posted a question on here so any feedback on how I can better phrase things is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined,

```
const ENDPOINT= "localhost:5000";
```

It should be,

```
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";
```